# PayPal Seamless Checkout for DG

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am working on integrating PayPal Seamless checkout. 
It is working for PayPal Express Checkout and PayPal Express Recurring but not working for the DG version of it.
Does PayPal support seamless checkout with IDENTITYACCESSTOKEN with Paypal Express DG?

Comment: Not really following.  The PaymentAction doesn't have anything to do with digital goods and wouldn't effect the checkout flow.

Comment: I am trying seamless checkout using the Access token
http://pastebin.com/JaAiQTqU
The second request works but not the first. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the response that you're getting back?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/DAgMEURg

Comment: What exactly isn't working?  It looks like you got a successful response there.

Comment: So, PayPalExpressCheckout is working, but PayPalExpressCheckout DG is not?
Not sure if it is my mistake or DG is not supported by PayPal, looked up the documentation but not sure.

Comment: I've used DG with Express Checkout many times without issues.  I'm still not seeing your issue.  All you've shown me is a successful request and response.

Comment: I can do payments with Express Checkout and Paypal Express Checkout DG. I can also make payments with PayPal Express Checkout with Seamless Checkout but if I pass the token with PayPal Express Checkout DG it asks me to login.